# Porque obtengo este error | Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position

Tags: php, javascript

[image: ERROR]

Buenas, actualmente estoy intentando realizar un sistema de "favoritos" resulta que funciona correctamente pero en la consola de mi navegador da este error y no entiendo porque sucede, he intentado buscar soluciones pero no logro entenderlas del todo. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

**index.php**

```
    <div class="anime-fav">
        <i <?php if (userLiked($post['id'])): ?>
      class="fas fa-heart favorite like-btn" 
  <?php else: ?>
      class="fas fa-heart single like-btn"
  <?php endif ?>
  data-id="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>"></i>
    </div>
```

**scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.like-btn').on('click', function(){
  var post_id = $(this).data('id');
  $clicked_btn = $(this);
  if ($clicked_btn.hasClass('single')) {
    action = 'like';
  } else if($clicked_btn.hasClass('favorite')){
    action = 'unlike';
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        'action': action,
        'post_id': post_id
    },
    success: function(data){
        res = JSON.parse(data);
        if (action == "like") {
            $clicked_btn.removeClass('favorite');
            $clicked_btn.addClass('single');
        } else if(action == "unlike") {
            $clicked_btn.removeClass('single');
            $clicked_btn.addClass('favorite');
        }
    }
  });       

});

});
```

Comment: Estos errores, por lo general, se deben a que la respuesta que espera es un JSON de JavaScript pero no es lo que recibe. Por lo general son respuestas string o de otro tipo, la cual al hacer JSON.parse, da errores.

Comment: @gaidyjg exacto. Al parecer esta analizando el texto recibido que se convertirá a JSON pero en php no a sido un JSON codificado (echo json_encode(...))